# how to put two fields result set in to array list in java

Tags: java

Here is my code: there is one database table field I m retrieving, but I want the second one too.

```
String query = "select QId, Options from QuestionMaster where SurveyID = '" + s + "'";

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

while (rs.next())
{
    list.add(rs.getString(1));
}
rs.close();
String[] contactListNames = (String[]) list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

is there any way to do this by 2d arraylist or 2d array

Comment: How *second one* is decided?

Comment: "QID" is the 1st field ,"Options" is the 2nd in query.I want "Options" field too in array list

Comment: rs.getString(2) ? Your question is quite vague 
Your query select QId, options and not names...

Comment: So you have to create an arrayList of a model with attributes QId and Options and fill that ArrayList with it.

Comment: @mcfly currently the arraylist is storing "QID" what want is QID = 1 , Options = 1 in arraylist example 1|1 , 2|1 , 3|2

Comment: Create a class with these two attributes and an arraylist with that type. For each entry create a new element of that new class type. Then you can access every attributes...

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place --- the question.

Comment: After you're done here, you may want to google "SQL Injection".

Answer (score 0):

If your ids are unique, you can use a `HashMap` to store the resultset:

```
   Map< String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
   while (rs.next()) {
       hm.put(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));     
    }

   Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> set = hm.entrySet();    

   for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : set) { 
       System.out.println(entry.getKey()); 
       System.out.println(entry.getValue()); 
   }
```

`entry.getKey()` returns `QId` and  
`entry.getValue()` returns `Options`

Comment: thanks for sharing but this is the only way to do this ?

Comment: The other way is to create a class with 2 fields and your list will store objects of this class.

Comment: I need to have the example what you last suggested.

Comment: There are a lot of sources to study for Java classes. One of them: https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-getter-and-setter-tutorial-from-basics-to-best-practices. You can google for more.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you create model class that fits to a table. 
Each query you do have to return that exact type so you know the entry is correct. 
(Won't go further but take a look at how Jpa or else works)

1. you create a class with all attributes (id, option, name...), let
   call this POJO
2. query your fields
3. iterate over each result and
   create your POJO  Object
4. add it to the list

there is plenty of other thing you could do here but this is the beginning of a database mapping